# How to use [(ngModel)] with FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular

I have these 3 input fields in my HTML:

```js
<mat-form-field>
    <input readOnly="readonly" name="aCertainNumberFromDatabase" formControlName="aCertainNumberFromDatabase" matInput type="number">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input readOnly="readonly" name="result" formControlName="result" matInput type="number">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input name="userInput" formControlName="userInput" matInput type="number">
</mat-form-field>
```

In `component.ts` I have this FormGroup:

```js
this.myform = myForm();

myForm() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    result: [this.result],
    userInput: [this.userInput],
    aCertainNumberFromDatabase: [this.aCertainNumberFromDatabase]
  })
```

When the user enters a number in the `userInput` field it should be added with a number from the database shown in the `aCertainNumberFromDatabase` field and the result should be automatically placed in the 
`result` field. How can I do this using `[(ngModel)]` and this `FormGroup`?

Comment: You can't mix template based forms with reactive forms.

Comment: You can set value of the `formControl` instead. Like: `this.myForm.controls.aCertainNumberFromDatabase.setValue(number);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reactive form, usually we don't use `ngModel`. You can set value using:

```
this.myForm.controls.aCertainNumberFromDatabase.setValue(value);
```

Once you get the value, you can set the value using above snippet.

Refer below demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-reactive-from-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

https://angular-sf-reactive-from-issue.stackblitz.io

Hope this will help.

Comment: But i want the result to show up directly when the user is entering his number. How should I do this? Where do I place this.myForm.controls.aCertainNumberFromDatabase.setValue(value);

Comment: and do you mean this.myForm.controls.result ?

Comment: You can use this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{ // Logic here });

Comment: I have added a demo for the same in stackblitz. Please refer: https://angular-sf-reactive-from-issue.stackblitz.io